# TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance beforeQuery flushing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two hibernate entities Coupon and CouponHistory with Uni Directional Relationship between CouponHistory and Coupon.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "validity_coupon")
public class Coupon {

@Id
@Column(length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
private String code;

private int validity;
private boolean used;

...}


@Entity
@Table(name = "coupon_history")
@TableGenerator(name = "seqGen", table = "shunya_id_gen", pkColumnName = "GEN_KEY", valueColumnName = "GEN_VALUE",
    pkColumnValue = "coupon_history_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class CouponHistory {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "seqGen")
private long id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdOn;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Coupon coupon;

...}
```

There is a Transactional Service Method that tries to saves both the entities in a Single Transaction. Spring is being used to handle transaction here.

```
@Transactional
public void createCoupon() {
    Coupon coupon = new Coupon();
    coupon.setCode(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5));
    coupon.setValidity(1);
    couponRepository.save(coupon);

    CouponHistory couponHistory = new CouponHistory();
    couponHistory.setCreatedOn(new Date());
    couponHistory.setCoupon(coupon);
    couponHistoryRepository.save(couponHistory);
}
```

I get the below exception when i call this method -

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance beforeQuery flushing : com.poc.CouponHistory.validityCoupon -> com.poc.Coupon; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance beforeQuery flushing : com.poc.CouponHistory.validityCoupon -> com.poc.Coupon
```

I don't understand why hibernate is complaining me when i have saved the child entity before parent entity in single transaction.

If i change id generation to Auto for Coupon Entity, then everything starts working fine. But i want to manually assign the Coupon Code so Id auto generation is not in scope.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not cascading coupon then you need it to be managed before saving CouponHistory, luckly when saving an entity save() will return the managed persisted entity so all you need is to assign it to coupon

```
 @Transactional
public void createCoupon() {
Coupon coupon = new Coupon();
coupon.setCode(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5));
coupon.setValidity(1);
coupon = couponRepository.save(coupon);//save will return the managed entity

CouponHistory couponHistory = new CouponHistory();
couponHistory.setCreatedOn(new Date());
couponHistory.setCoupon(coupon);
couponHistoryRepository.save(couponHistory);
}
```

Comment: Does Repository's save method returns a new instance. I was under impression that save object is assigned a Id?

Comment: @MunishChandel yes it returns new instance attached to the persistence context

Answer (score 1):

Try to wire the entity manager with `@PersistenceContext` and do `this.entityManager.flush()` after saving the `Coupon`.

Hibernate is trying to wait with persisting entities as much as possible (usually until the transaction gets closed) and you can 'force' that by flushing explicitly.